# What does "Pitch Correction" do in Rock Band 3?

Tags: rock-band-3

I just started playing Rock Band 3 and I noticed that there is an option for vocals called "Pitch Correction".  What does this actually do?  Does it change the scoring at all?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it doesn't have any effect on scoring, it just makes your voice sound better coming out of the speakers.  [Joystiq](http://www.joystiq.com/2010/06/29/rock-band-3s-pitch-correction-provided-by-izotope/) puts it this way:

> The game will use [iZotope's real-time pitch detection and correction](http://www.izotope.com/tech/omega/) to make you sound less like yourself and more like someone who can hit a damn note occasionally.